# Subsetting Data Based on Number of Rows True

Tags: r, sorting, filter, row, multiple-columns

In R, I have a dataset with 10 columns of interest. These columns are binary, where 1 means true and 2 means false. I need to subset the data to find the number of times at which only 2 columns equal 1, only 3 columns equal 1, etc. The issue- I don't care which 3 equal 1, I just need data on how many times it occurs that any combination of 3 equals 1.

This is the only way I have been able to find this, but I have to write all this code for each combination, and this is way too tedious with 1023 possible combinations.

`a1x3 <- filter(ALL_STATES_TBL, ace3 == "1" & ace4 == "2" & ace5 == "2" & ace6 == "2" & ace7 == "2" & ace8 == "2" & ace9 == "2")`
`a1x3t <- filter(a1x3, ace1 == "3")`
`a1x3tt <- filter(a1x3, ace1 == "4")`
`a1x3 <- rbind(a1x3t, a1x3tt)`

Any help would be greatly appreciated! [Also, code is written this way because ace1 has 4 options instead of 2].

Answer (score 0):

We could iteratively subset by `n` columns, equal to `== 1` and count the `rowSums` how many times they are `n`. `combn` does the all combinations job.

```
f <- \(x) {
  sq <- seq_along(x)[-1]
  sapply(setNames(sq, sq), \(n) 
         sum(unlist(combn(ncol(x), n, \(j) rowSums(as.data.frame(x)[, j] == 1) == n))))
}
```

Consider this data frame.

```
dat1
#   V1 V2 V3 V4
# 1  1  2  1  1
# 2  1  2  2  2
# 3  1  2  1  1
# 4  1  2  2  1
    
# 2 3 4 
# 7 2 0
```

Or this one

```
dat2
#   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10
# 1  1  2  1  1  1  2  2  2  1   2
# 2  1  2  2  2  1  1  2  1  1   2
# 3  1  2  1  2  1  1  2  2  2   2
# 4  1  1  2  2  1  1  2  2  2   2
# 5  2  2  1  2  1  1  1  2  2   1

f(dat2)
#  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 
# 42 38 17  3  0  0  0  0  0
```

---

*Data:*

```
set.seed(42)
dat1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(1:2, 16, replace=TRUE), 4, 4))

set.seed(42)
dat2 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(1:2, 50, replace=TRUE), 5, 10))
```

Comment: Thanks so much! My problem is "j" seems to need a specific column name, and I'm evaluating 10 columns? It worked when I ran exactly the code you suggested, but I attempted to apply this to my own data and got an error concerning "j".

Comment: @Ivey Make your error reproducible for me, See https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/6574038

Comment: Example set of data: structure(list(year = c(2016, 2016, 2016, 2017), fipsst = c(1, 2, 2, 3), ace1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4), ace3 = c(1, 2, 1, 2), ace4 = c(1, 1, 1, 2), ace5 = c(1, 2, 2, 2), ace6 = c(1, 1, 1, 1), ace7 = c(1, 2, 1, 2), ace8 = c(1, 2, 2, 2), ace9 = c(1, 1, 1, 2), ace10 = c(2, 2, 2, 2), ace11 = c(2, 2, 1, 2), class = "data.frame"); when I run f() I receive "Error in `[.data.table`(x, , j) : 
  j (the 2nd argument inside [...]) is a single symbol but column name 'j' is not found. Perhaps you intended DT[, ..j]. Difference to data.frame is deliberate.
Called from: `[.data.table`(x, , j)"

Comment: I also tried the original f with sum instead of rowSums to combat this error (I removed the year and fips columns as well and renamed all columns ace to get around j error-) code now looks like "f <- \(x) {
  sq <- seq_along(x)[-1]
  sapply(setNames(sq, sq), \(n) 
         sum(unlist(combn(ncol(x), n, \(ace) sum(x[, ace, drop = FALSE] == 1) == n))))
}". However, applying this just returns NAs.

Comment: @Ivey You have class `'data.table'` (try `class(<your data>)`), not sure why it doesn't work with it, but they are slightly different from `'data.frame'`. I've added a line in the function, should work now.

Comment: @ivey Be sure to only select specific columns to get correct results, e.g. `f(dat[, 3:12])` in your example.